# C#/XNA extensions setting instance properties

Tags: c#, vector, xna

I'm making an extension to the Vector2 class.  In my main code, I can say

```
Vector2 v=new Vector2();
v.X=2;
```

But in my extension, I can't.

```
public static void SetToThree(this Vector2 vector)
{
    vector.X=3;       
}
```

v.SetToThree() doesn't change v.
When I go line by line through the code, in the extension vector's X direction is changed to 3, but after the extension is finished, and the main code is continued, v hasn't changed at all.
Is there any way for the extension method SetToThree to change v's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though it *looks* like an instance method, it operates like a static method - so `arg0` (`this`) is not `ref` - it is passed-by-value, hence you are mutating a *copy* of the struct. Since you *can't* use `ref` on the first argument of an extension method, you would have to `return` it instead:

```
public static Vector2 SetToThree(this Vector2 vector)
{
    vector.X=3;
    return vector;
}
```

and use:

```
v = v.SetToThree();
```

So possibly not worth it...

Comment: Or, if possible, make Vector a Class (which should be passed-by-Reference) instead of a Struct (passed-by-value).

Comment: @Andy - that is a common existing XNA type.